# Not able to see any LWC HTML content

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to display LWC HTML content in browser but I am not able to see anything.

I am adding `showLibrary` LWC app in `TestLWC.app`. I am not using any namespace.

**TestLWC.app**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
     <c:showLibrary></c:showLibrary>
</aura:application>
```

**showLibrary.html**

```
<template>

<lightning-card title="HelloWorld" icon-name="custom:custom14">
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
      <p>Hello, {greeting}!</p>
      <lightning-input label="Name" value={greeting} onchange={changeHandler}></lightning-input>
    </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**showLibrary.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class showLibrary extends LightningElement {
    greeting = 'World';
    changeHandler(event) {
        this.greeting = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

**showLibrary.js-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <apiVersion>50.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <targets>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: I copy-pasted into my org--it runs fine. It is unusual to change the name of your class from the component name (I'd expect it to be called `ShowLibrary` instead of `ShowTrustPortalLibrary`), but that doesn't change anything. It still works. Make sure you don't have any compilation errors, and also, check your Developer Console (F12 in your browser) to see if you get any errors.

Comment: https://webcomponents.dev/edit/oEXrwKZP9q5kY86Puot6/src/app.js

Comment: @sfdcfox It is intermittent. It started working after I asked this question and then it stoped working. When I checked with chrome inspect , this is what I found.

DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://ttt.lightning.force.com/javascript/1515605724000/ui-sfdc-javascript-impl/source/RecordGVP.js.map: Unexpected end of JSON input
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://ttt.lightning.f

Comment: That's not an error, just a debugger warning that the original source code isn't available. It will not stop components/apps from loading.